# Are there any guarantees about vulkan command buffer execution order outside of semaphore usage?

Tags: synchronization, vulkan

My understanding is that you need a semaphore to synchronize execution between two different command buffers. Is this always the case?

For instance, could commands within a single buffer potentially execute out of order? Or does this only occur with multiple?

Comment: Semaphores are for synchronization between *queues*. Timeline semaphores can be used to synchronize operations on the same queue.

Comment: Can you rephraze your question in a way that it is clearer what you are getting at? Yes, there are "guarantees" outside Sempahores that inform about the state of command buffers; e.g. Fences. You don't "need" to synchronize execution between two command buffers, unless you require to do so. Commands withing a single command buffer can execute out of order, but what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: I'm asking a general question about what the guarantees about command buffer are execution are. If commands within a single command buffer can be executed out of order, does that mean multiple buffers can also be executed in whatever order the driver wants?

Comment: This sounds like something that would quickly devolve into "explain the whole synchronization system". All of the async stuff executes in whatever way it feels like except for explicit, and a few implicit synchronization gurantees.